# How to compute pixel-wise median of N images in openCV without creating a manual loop?

Tags: image, opencv, matrix, median

Is there a better way to do this without looping through each pixel (row, column) and computing the median for each pixel across images?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it for N=3 using

```
min(max(a, b), max(b, c), max(a,c))
```